# What is the word for the different "slots" in a budget?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

When you set up a budget, you have a new "slot" for each item, right? What do you call such slots? *Budget entry*? *Budget post*? Something else entirely?

Note that I'm not talking about the various sums of money you put aside for each item; I just want to know what you call the actual slots/posts/entries in the actual, physical budget. A little bit like we talk about entries in a dictionary, for instance.

Comment: *When you set up a budget, you have a new "slot" for each item, right?* No, not necessarily... I don't think I do. I would call them "an allocation".

Comment: Budget targets?

Comment: @Greybeard Uh... huh? Haha, that was a rhetorical question, really... so when you create a budget you just write everything down in one line? You don't have one slot/post/entry – whatever – for food; one for hygiene; one for leisure... etc?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko So you'd say, for instance, "I have a budget with six different targets"? Would it be wrong to use "entry"?

Comment: This document describes them as categories. https://mint.intuit.com/mint-categories

Comment: [line item](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/line_item)?

Comment: @JavaLatte Thanks! Would it be wrong to use "entry" though?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Thanks! Would it be wrong to use "entry" though?

Comment: Not at all. "Entry" is a perfectly good usage for this. However, it's also a very broad usage; when spending under your budget includes multiple expenditures for a particular line item, the record of each is also legitimately called an "entry" - for example, if the line item for housing in your annual budget is $36,000, each monthly expenditure of $3,000 would be recorded as a separate entry in your records.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Excellent! Thank you! (And I hope my thank you will be left long enough for you to see it :) I've upvoted your comment as well)

Comment: bucket is another alternative.

Comment: Entry depends entirely on what report you are looking at. An entry in a summary might be a for group of categories: an entry in a detail ledger would be for one particular item- for one advertisement that is included in the advertising budget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are simply called "items", or possibly "categories".

When making *accounts*, each line in a ledger is an "entry". However, all entries are collated at the end of a financial year and grouped into 'items'. Accounts that detail each *kind* of income and expenditure, rather than just give a total profit/loss, are called "itemised accounts".

A budget is grouped from the start, because it looks forward to a new financial period just as a set of accounts looks back at one that has passed. Like accounts, a budget can be "itemised". A single figure representing a total amount of money could be called a "budget", but if a document breaks it down into kinds of income and expense, it is an *itemised budget*.